# Dagger2 "test" class generated but not able to import it

Tags: android, testing, gradle, code-generation, dagger-2

So basically I can see that my DaggerTestComponent is generated in apt/adnroidTest/debug/...

but I can't import it, it keep saying cannot resolve symbol...

```
public class TestComponentRule implements TestRule {

private final TestComponent mTestComponent;
private final Context mContext;

public TestComponentRule(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    LGCApplication application = LGCApplication.get(context);
    mTestComponent = DaggerTestComponent.builder()
            .applicationTestModule(new ApplicationTestModule(application))
            .build();
}
```

And for the revelant part of the gradle:

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        def commonTestDir = 'src/commonTest/java'
        test {
            java.srcDir commonTestDir
        }
        androidTest {
            java.srcDir commonTestDir
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.9"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.9"
    testAnnotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.9"
    androidTestAnnotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.9"
    provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28' //Required by Dagger2
}
```

And it's only for the testComponent, the DaggerComponent for my application is added successfully.

Comment: In which folder is the generated file that you are trying to import? Is it in `src/commonTest/java`?

Comment: no it's in : androidTest/debug/.../test/common/injection/component
basically I'm using: https://github.com/ribot/android-boilerplate
but when I build their project, it builds without trouble, eventhough I just checked and I have the same error... but at least when I build I get no error, with my project I can run, but if I do a full build, it'll crash

Comment: It sounds like the problem is that the generated files are not being included in your `androidTest` source set. I remember seeing another question like this where there was a some gradle code to make sure that Dagger 2 generated the files in the right directory for `androidTest`. Perhaps you can find it if you do some more googling - it's not the first time a question like this has been asked on StackOverflow